# Cmd not recognising 7zip

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, path, 7zip

My bat script (new.bat):

```
7z x –oC:\Users\Toshiba\Downloads\* C:\Users\Toshiba\Downloads\*.zip

del C:\Users\Toshiba\Downloads\*.zip
```

Despite using the command line version of 7zip, if i run my batch script, i get:

> 7z x ΓÇôoC:\Users\Toshiba\Downloads* C:\Users\Toshiba\Downloads*.zip
>   '7z' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> del C:\Users\Toshiba\Downloads*.zip
>   C:\Users\Toshiba\Downloads\XT1032_RETAIL-EU_4.4.4_KXB21.14-L1.40_36_cid7_CFC_1FF.xml.zip
>   Access is denied.

[Here are my instructions](http://www.guidingtech.com/24662/automatically-extract-zip-files/). It asks me to edit the *PATH* User variable under *Enviromental variables*, but as there wasn't one i created it like so:

```
Variable Name: Path

Variable Value:C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\;C:\Users\Toshiba\Documents\new.bat
```

Comment: Have you restarted your command shell? How about Windows itself? PATH changes have to be applied.

Comment: The last `path` entry containing `.bat` is wrong, absolutely remove it. To temporarily remove it (in current `cmd` session) try `set "path=%path:;C:\Users\Toshiba\Documents\new.bat=%"`.

Answer (score 1):

- That `ΓÇô` in the error message means that instead of the hyphen `-` you've used [En dash](http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x2013/index.html).
- `'7z' is not recognized` means either that it's not in a folder defined in `PATH` variable or you have saved the batch file with a unicode signature (byte order mark).
- `Access is denied` error may indicate the file is opened somewhere or maybe it has a readonly attribute which you can clear by adding `attrib -r C:\Users\Toshiba\Downloads\*.zip` on a new line before `del`.

Solution: use the correct hyphen <kbd>-</kbd>, specify a full path for `7z` in quotes (for example, `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"`) and resave the file in plain encoding (ANSI in Windows Notepad, for example), not UTF-8, not UTF-16.

Comment: Well done. However, `'7z' is not recognized` has nothing to do with _Unicode_ `BOM` which would return something jike `'˙ţ7' is not recognized` (CP 1250) or `'ÿþ7' is not recognized` (CP 1252) or `'■7' is not recognized` (CP 437) etc. It's `path` issue...

Comment: Ah, yes, but maybe the OP didn't select the error message entirely. Anyway, I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: The delete command is working fine, but now the system "cannot find the path specified", like so: 
`"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -oC:\Users\Toshiba\Downloads\* C:\Users\Toshiba\Downloads\*.zip
The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: @ErljaJkdf, `-o` sets the output directory for extraction, not the files *to extract*.

Comment: How can i select all zip files to be extracted?

Comment: Simply remove `*` from `-o` parameter.